# WPF devexpress datagrid - CanExecute is not refreshed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, icommand

I'm using devexpress datagrid to build my wpf application. I've very simple gird with 2 columns. Second column contains buttons with plus sign. Buttons are binded to Command in ViewModel (with CanExecute implementaion).

The whole point is that "CanExecute" is not executed and Buttons are refreshed correctly, especially when I'm scrolling a grid.

Below 2 screnns

[image: Correct button state]

*Correct button state*

[image: Button state not refreshed]

*Button state not refreshed*

Devexpress DataGrid uses rows [virtualization](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6120), so there are only few rows created and only data is changing.

I've almost solved my problem but my solution is not good enough to accept that.
I've noticed that I've to call

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

So I've added dummy converter that always return the same value but also calls that method above

```
class DummyIsEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm using my converter with some useless binding, but every time when row model is changed convert method is called and "Add button" gets correct state.

**Edited**

My XAML code

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="AddComponentCellTemplate">
    <Grid >
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=itemsGrid, Path=DataContext.AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RowData.Row}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddTemplate}">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
 ....
<dxg:GridControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="itemsGrid" IsFilterEnabled="False">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Header="Name"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="" Header="" Width="20" FixedWidth="True"  CellTemplate="{DynamicResource AddComponentCellTemplate}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView  Style="{StaticResource defaultTableViewStyle}" />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the devexpress `DataGrid`. DOes this happen with the usual `DataGrid` too? You could hook yourself into `DAatCOntextChanged` event of `DataGridCell`, and use setters to set `Command`. It should re-evaluate the complete binding.

Comment: I don't think that it is a bug. Look, my button's IsEnabled property is not bounded to any of my model's property. Even 'CanExecute' is not 'binded' to any of my model's property.

Comment: As long as your `Button` `Command` property is binded against command, enabled/disabled functionality will work automatically. Note: you have to call yourCommmand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); if the command status changes. Try posting the xaml of your button.